# cannot catch MySQL IntegrityError in Python

Tags: python, mysql, exception, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I am using Python/Bottle/SqlAlchemy/MySQL for a web service.

I am trying to catch an `IntegrityError` raised by calling a stored procedure but I am unable to do that.

Using this

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.callproc('my_stored_proc', [arguments])
```

yields the same result as

```
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('my_stored_proc', [arguments])
except IntegrityError as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))
    return {"message": e.message}
```

I get an `IntegrityError` exception in both cases. Why is the exception not caught in the latter case?

Comment: How / when are you committing your transaction? The `IntegrityError` will likely be raised when your transaction gets committed, not when calling the stored procedure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was I was catching the incorrect exception.

It turned out the error raised is actually of type `pymysql.err.IntegrityError` and not `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError` as I assumed.

I found out the exception type by doing:

```
import sys
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('my_stored_proc', [arguments])
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

And I saw this printout:

```py
Unexpected error: <class 'pymysql.err.IntegrityError'>
```

Comment: just to add since I had a similar problem. I couldnt catch it either. I had to import pymysql; except pymysql.IntegrityError;

Answer (score 4):

In my case, and also yours, you'd use the sqlalchemy object:

```
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('my_stored_proc', [arguments])
except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))
    return {"message": e.message}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case and may be this helps you too, I was using MYSQL as database so to catch exceptions I need to import exceptions

```
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
```

Then you can try and catch it like this

```
try:
    #your code
except IntegrityError:
    #your code when integrity error comes
```

Comment: OP is asking about `pymysql`, not Django.

Answer (score 0):

With pymysql I use:

```
import pymysql
# some code

try:
   #Your code
except pymysql.err.IntegrityError:
   # Your exception code
except Exception as e:
   # Raise all other exceptions. 
   raise e
```